# How to use vue mixin in this situation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins, vue-mixin

I have the following code in two vue component:

```
  data() {
    return {
      overlay: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("toggleSidebar", status => (this.overlay = status));
  }
```

How can I use this in mixin?

this is my mixin (toggle.js)

```
import EventBus from "@/eventBus";

const toggle = () => {
  return {
    data() {
      return {
        show: false
      };
    },
    created() {
      EventBus.$on("toggleSidebar", status => (this.show = status));
    }
  };
};

export default toggle;
```

But I can't use it

Comment: You should definitly deregister from the eventbus in the beforeDestroy method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import EventBus from "@/eventBus";

const toggle = {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("toggleSidebar", status => (this.show = status));
  }
};

export default toggle;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.